# How to enable password lock on Notes in iOS 9.3?

Tags: ios, icloud, password, notes.app

I recently got iOS 9.3 for my iPhone, but I'm not finding an obvious way to password-lock my Notes. This feature was advertised by Apple as part of the iOS 9.3 package, but is it only available for certain devices, similarly to Night Shift?

I'm using an iPhone 5C, but the problem also seems to be occurring on my iPad Air 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relatively difficult-to-find solution to the problem is to go to the Note you wish to lock:

- in the top-right corner, tap the "Share" icon
- on the bottom row, there will be a lock symbol with a caption that says "Lock Note".
- select that symbol
- you will be prompted to create a password that locks this note, but remember that this **single password will secure all your protected notes**, not just the note you're on.

You can also use Touch ID to secure your notes. Remember that if you secure the note, it will no longer be accessible by devices running versions of OS X older than 10.11.4, or devices running a version of iOS different from 9.3 or higher. Next time you try to open that Note (or others that are locked with the passcode), you'll be prompted for your password to unlock it.

You can change the Notes password by going to your Home screen, then Settings > Notes > Password.

Answer (score 0):

Angelplayer's directions are great. Except **be sure your note is in iCloud Notes.** If the note has options to handwrite on it (a squiggly button in the bottom toolbar of the note), then it is in iCloud; otherwise it is not.

If you use Gmail or another non-iCloud service to sync your notes, Apple will not let you lock them (they would still be visible in Gmail and Apple does not want to give you false confidence about the secrecy of the notes).

How to set up iCloud Notes: Go to Settings on your iPhone/iPad, tap iCloud, then toggle on Notes.

Once your notes are synced with iCloud, you can tap the export button in the top left of a note and tap "Lock Note."